# Content Security Policy violation with Bootstrap 5

Tags: content-security-policy, bootstrap-5

I have a site using Bootstrap 5 that includes the following input tag:

```
<input class="form-check-input ms-1" id="validated" name="validated" type="checkbox" checked>
```

The inclusion of the form-check-input class causes the client to generate the error message:

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg
> xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath
> fill='none' stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round'
> stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='M6 10l3
> 3l6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e' because it violates the following Content
> Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' www.w3.org".

Can someone please lend me a clue as to why this is being blocked?  I have tried all the permutations of data://www.w3.org, http://www.w3.org, *.w3.org, etc., in the CSP and none seem to satisfy the client.

This happens identically with a Chrome and Edge client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap [CSS stylesheet](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css) contains `.form-check-input` class with data:-Url images:

```
.form-check-input:checked[type=checkbox] {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='M6 10l3 3l6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
.form-check-input:checked[type=radio] {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='2' fill='%23fff'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
.form-check-input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate {
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border-color: #0d6efd;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='M6 10h8'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

To allow these images you have to add `data:` scheme-source into `img-src` directive.

Comment: Hello granty. could you give an example of the entry you are speaking about? Thanks.

Comment: Mathias, my img-src declaration is now "img-src": [ "'self'", "data:" ] and it is working.

Answer (score 4):

You can also extract the SVGs into separate files using Webpack.  For example, see the official documentation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/webpack/#extracting-svg-files

```js
modules.exports = {
  ...,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
        scheme: 'data',
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'icons/[hash].svg'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```